# Generate random data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to generate a random quote from data obtained through an api. I generated a random index but when I click on the corresponding button I'm not getting back a random quote. I'm not getting any apparent errors.

```
randomQuote() {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotes.length);
    return this.quotes[index]
  },
```

Here's my data object.

```
data: {
    data: [],
    quotes: [],
    currentIndex: 0,
    currentPage: 1,
  },
```

Here's my axios call:

```
axios.get(url).then(res => {
        this.data = res.data;
        this.quotes = this.data;
      });
```

Comment: What does the <button> look like?  I'd suggest at least pasting in the .vue file, or if possible a full repro in Codesandbox

Comment: @tony please show us what the markup for the button looks like and the method it is calling. The above tells us nothing

Answer (score 1):

There is an apparent error in your `axios` call, you are not setting `quotes` to the correct object:

```js
axios.get(url).then(res => {
  this.quotes = res.data.quotes;
});
```

Comment: I'm able to get all the quotes with the code I have. My issue is when I click on the generate random button it doesn't work. So it looks like I am setting it to the correct object.

Comment: @tony Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony Definitely not with the code you have attached to your question.